# I am attempting to define a class which can only be instantiated on the heap

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to achieve this by overloading the delete operator as a friend function. The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>


class HeapOnly
{
    int x;
    int y;
    ~HeapOnly()
    {

    }
public:
    void friend operator delete(void* a);
};

void operator delete(void* p)
{
    delete p;
}

int main()
{
    HeapOnly *abc = new HeapOnly();
    delete abc;
}
```

The above code gives error in Visual Studio "Error  C2248   'HeapOnly::~HeapOnly': cannot access private member declared in class 'HeapOnly"

I do not understand as to why it is giving error as the delete operator is overloaded as friend function hence it should be able to access the destructor which is in private.

Comment: Why don't you want objects of this type to have any other storage duration?

Comment: Have you considered a private constructor, with new instances being obtained with a static method that returns a pointer instead? Also, why exactly do you need such a class?

Comment: _"I am attempting to define a class which can only be instantiated on the heap
"_ - I don't understand why, but what about making all the constructors private and provide a factory static member function that create instances on the heap?

Comment: `delete` is not an operator, and unlike when overloading actual operators, `delete abc` is not syntactic sugar for an invocation of `operator delete`. `operator delete` has a confusing name and would more appropriately be called "deallocate" or "free" or something like that, but "the C++ way" is to overload the meaning of existing reserved words rather than introducing new ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really a "delete operator" for you to overload. There are:

- *Delete expression*, as in `delete abc`; and
- *Deallocation function* which deallocate memory, and its syntax is, confusingly, `operator delete`.

In other words, you have never overloaded the non-existent "delete operator" or declaring it a friend. The only thing overloaded and declared a friend is the *deallocation function*.

The *delete expression* does thing in two steps:

1. Invoke the destructor to reduce the object back into raw memory
2. Invoke the deallocation function to deallocate the memory

Therefore, the private destructor is still considered invoked directly by `main`, which is not a friend of the class.

We can do a little experiment to verify that:

Code 1: Without `friend` declaration: https://godbolt.org/g/WVmzNP

```
class HeapOnly
{
    int x;
    int y;
    ~HeapOnly() = default;
};

int main()
{
    HeapOnly *abc = new HeapOnly();
    delete abc;
}
```

Code 2: Declaring `main` as friend: https://godbolt.org/g/9PVZ4C

```
class HeapOnly
{
    int x;
    int y;
    ~HeapOnly() = default;

    friend int main();
};

int main()
{
    HeapOnly *abc = new HeapOnly();
    delete abc;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As why your attempt failed, see other answers. I don't know whether, and if so how, you can achieve the general goal of a class that can only be instantiated on the heap and if this is desirable, but I doubt both.

However, what you can do is to restrict de-allocation to go through `std::allocator` or `std::default_delete`, so that simple automatic variables are not possible:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class HeapOnly
{
    ~HeapOnly();
  public:
    bool operator < (HeapOnly const&) const;
    friend class std::allocator<HeapOnly>;
    friend class std::default_delete<HeapOnly>;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<HeapOnly> X(10);   // okay
    HeapOnly Y;                    // ERROR: cannot be destructed
    std::sort(X.begin(),X.end());  // ERROR: requires automatic variables
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<HeapOnly>> Z(10);    // okay
    for(auto&z:Z)
        z.reset(new HeapOnly);
    std::sort(Z.begin(),Z.end(),[](std::unique_ptr<HeapOnly> const&x,
                                   std::unique_ptr<HeapOnly> const&y)
                                { return *x < *y; }); 
}
```

Note, however, that many things rely on automatic variables, including `std::swap` and `std::sort` (befriending `std::sort` directly does not help, as it delegates the work to implementation-specific helper routines). However, you can enable `unique_ptr` (and `shared_ptr`), which appears the natural thing to do with a heap-only class, and sort the objects pointed to.

**Note further** that even though the code above may work with most if not all STL implementations, this is **not guaranteed**. `std::allocator<>::destroy()` may, for example, delegate the destruction to a helper function, which is an implementation detail and hence cannot be befriended.

However, you could test for this and use SFINAE to dodge such cases.

Comment: @GauravSehgal Ummm... Only allow `std::allocator<HeapOnly>` to call the destructor, and no one else?

Comment: Only that this solution does not allow using "raw" pointers with `new` and `delete`. Of course better to avoid them, but we don't know whether OP needs them or not.

Comment: @DanielLangr Ermh. Well, I think I stated at the beginning, that I don't know whether/how to achieve that (raw pointers yet heap-only).

Comment: your `friend` way is *not portable*, those implementations might use helper class/function.

Comment: @Jarod42 I was dreading this too. But are you sure? AFAIK, `allocator` does not use helper functions. I don't know about `default_delete`, but if you can provide me with a proof (quote from the standard and/or cppreference) that would be useful.

Comment: Standard state the behaviour/complexity of functions, not the implementation. And using helper methods might be possible.